# Graficos 3d interactivos con Jupyter Notebook. Error Javascript Error: IPython is not defined

Tags: javascript, python, matplotlib, jupyter, 3d

buen fin de semana.
Estoy intentando hacer unos graficos 3D con jupyter notebook, pude imprimirlos cuando utilizo `%matplotlib inline`.
Pero me gustaria poder girarlo y hacerlo interactivo, para ello utilizo `%matplotlib notebook`. Cuando utilizo este ultimo tengo el siguiente error:   Error Javascript Error: IPython is not defined.

Se puede solucionar? Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Hola Gastón creo que lo que buscas es usar el siguiente [módulo](https://github.com/matplotlib/ipympl) de python conjunto de `%matplotlib widget`